# Postman Assertion

Tags: postman, chai

I have problem relating to assertion during practicing.

I have response body like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "manufacturer": "Ford",
        "model": "Model T",
        "build": 1927
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "manufacturer": "Tesla",
        "model": "Model 3",
        "build": 2017
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "manufacturer": "Tesla",
        "model": "Cybertruck",
        "build": 2019
    }
]
```

I wrote test

```
const response = pm.response.json()
 
let model;
 
for (let filter of response) {
    if (filter.model === "Model 3") {
       //console.log(filter)
       model = filter;
    }
}
console.log(model)
 
pm.test("car model is Model 3", function () {
    pm.expect(response.model).to.eql("Model 3");
});
```

Unfortunately, my test fail `AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal 'Model 3'`  I was trying to figure out but dunno why this is not passing because my navigation to that model is correct. Can you guide me what is wrong with my code please.

Comment: Change for this line:

pm.expect(model).to.eql("Model 3");

response is an array and response.model is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.model` is `undefined` since `response` is an array.
You probably forgot to use `model.model` instead of `response.model`

```js
pm.test("car model is Model 3", function () {
    pm.expect(model.model).to.eql("Model 3");
});
```